# Configure applications using environment variables

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, 12factor

[12-Factor Apps](http://12factor.net/) suggest that you [configure](http://12factor.net/config) your application using environment variables. So far, so good. I can easily imagine that this is a good way to do it if you need to set a connection string, e.g.

But what if you have more complex configuration with lots and lots of values? I for sure do not want to have 50+ environment variables, do I?

How could I solve this, and still be compliant to the idea of 12-Factor Apps?

Comment: “I for sure do not want to have 50+ environment variables, do I?” Why not?

Comment: Because it gets unnecessarily complicated while developing, or am I missing something?

Comment: It’s probably me that’s missing something, as I’m not very familiar with using environment variables, but in what way is it more complicated than whatever you’re doing at the moment? (Separately, [here’s a good critique of the config chapter of the 12 Factor manifesto](http://quest.windwards.net/content/twelve-factor-app).)

Comment: At the moment, I start my app using `node app.js`. I do not want to provide 50+ environment variables manually, and I also do not want to edit a file each time, if I want to experiment with some settings.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick read of the [configure](http://12factor.net/config) link you provided, I agree with the author's claim that there is a widespread problem, but I am not convinced that their proposed solution is going to always be best. Like you, I don't relish the idea of having to define dozens of environment variables to configure an application. So here are some alternative ideas.

First, read [Chapter 2 of the *Config4* Getting Started Guide*](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-config4star-syntax.html) (disclaimer: I am the main author of that software). In particular, notice that its support for what I call *adaptive configuration* can go a long way towards addressing the concern that you ask about. Is Config4* the ultimate solution? Possibly not, but I think it is a good step in the right direction.

Second, the chances are that whatever application you are developing/maintaining has already settled on a particular configuration technology, such as XML files or Java property files, and it won't be feasible to migrate to using Config4*. This raises the question: is there anything you can do to avoid having a proliferation of, say, XML-based configuration files when you have multiple environments (such as dev, UAT, staging and production) in which the application will be deployed? I have outlined an approach for dealing with this issue in another StackOverflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762211/manage-configuration-files-across-environments/13828784#13828784).